# Отменить выбор в Combobox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

У меня есть Combobox с данными.

```
<ComboBox
    Grid.Row="4" 
    Name="AddSubLocationCheckBox"
    Height="40"
    Background="White"
    Visibility="Visible"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListLocations, Mode=OneWay}"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    PlaceholderText="Set as Sub-Location"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedLocation, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Margin="0,30,10,0" />
```

Есть ли возможность отменить выбор в Combobox если я случайно нажал на вариант в нем, но это поле в данной для меня ситуации должно оставаться пустым? Спасибо!

Comment: SelectedLocation=null, не?

Comment: Если поле должно оставаться пустым, может стоит поле просто задизейблить? Чтобы юзер не мог его менять

Comment: Я не понимаю. Если я случайно выберу что-то из списка, selectedLocation уже не будет равно нулю и данные при дальнейшей обработке уже не будут приравниваться null. А мне нужно отменить мой выбор прям на xaml где находиться этот combobox. Типо кнопки сбоку "Cancel", и она отменить случайный выбор и SelectedLocation приравняет нулю. Но если способ отменить не прибегая к этой доп кнопке?

Comment: Это поле не должно оставаться пустым, юзер должен иметь возможность выбрать локацию, и также отменить свой выбор.

Comment: ну так привяжите к кнопке команду и выполните в ней `SelectedLocation = null`

Comment: Я так понимаю более красивого способа, кроме как кнопки нету?

Comment: Более красивого способа, чем сделать именно то, что требуется?

Comment: Ну как вариант крестик в combobox, как есть TextBox.

Comment: В чем конкретно вопрос-то? Вы не знаете как сбросить значение в ComboBox или не можете шаблон какой-то реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил просто кнопку рядом, для отмены выбора(если пользователь выбрал, а потом передумал оставлять имя Локации(SelectedLocation), и поле должно быть пустым). Свойства и функции combobox, button привожу ниже:

```
            <ComboBox
            Grid.Row="4" 
            Name="AddSubLocationCheckBox"
            Height="40"
            Width="300"
            Background="White"
            Visibility="Visible"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListLocations, Mode=OneWay}"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            PlaceholderText="Set as Sub-Location"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedLocation, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Margin="0,30,10,0"/>

        <Button
            Grid.Row="4"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="40"
            Height="40"
            Background="{StaticResource WhiteSolidColorBrush}"
            Tapped="CancelSubLocation_Tapped"
            Visibility="{x:Bind CancelSubLocation, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Margin="0,30,10,0">
            <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE711;" Foreground="Black"/>
        </Button>

    public ComboBoxLocationItem SelectedLocation
    {
        get { return (ComboBoxLocationItem)GetValue(SelectedLocationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedLocationProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedLocationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectedLocation), typeof(ComboBoxLocationItem), typeof(AddLocationControl), new PropertyMetadata(null,
            (o, args) => ((AddLocationControl)o).CheckSubLocation()));

    public bool CancelSubLocation
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(CancelSubLocationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CancelSubLocationProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CancelSubLocationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CancelSubLocation), typeof(bool), typeof(AddLocationControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public void CheckSubLocation()
    {
        if (SelectedLocation != null)
        {
            CancelSubLocation = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CancelSubLocation = false;
        }
    }

    private void CancelSubLocation_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CancelSubLocation = false;
        SelectedLocation = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Значение `SelectedIndex=-1` у комбобокса должно его очистить